# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: get.flocker.io

Tags: curl

I'm trying to install flockerctl on my ubuntu14.04 machine by using the command     `curl -sSL https://get.flocker.io |sh`
as provided at [flocker site](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/flocker-features/flockerctl.html).
But the curl command is giving me error as-
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: get.flocker.io`
I'm not able to debug it as no information is printed as part of the log. Does anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/get.flocker.io

*"It's not just you! http://get.flocker.io looks down from here."*

IOW: the name doesn't resolve.

Comment: ok. It means site is down. Do I need to contact flocker provider ?

Comment: yes you do, not even "flocker.io" resolves for me